# Library for drag and drop to specific areas

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, drag-and-drop

What library can I use to implement the following kind of functionality
on Linux:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/65774455@N08/5983551492/in/photostream/

http://www.flickr.com/photos/65774455@N08/5983551494/in/photostream/

My goal is a locally installed app so stuff like JQuery is out of the question.

Preferred languages are C, Perl. But it doesn't have to be strictly confined to those 2 languages.

Any hints to which part of the library I should look at will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case your question is still up to date:

You could take a look at QT, which is a very good gui framework (KDE is built on top of QT) http://qt.nokia.com/. It really has tons of features and stuff, and you can of course build GUIs that support drag & drop. The framework is in C++ though.

The GTK framework (base of the gnome desktop environment) has C as well as C++ libs (http://www.gtk.org/).

Of course there are other gui libraries and frameworks for linux (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits), I for one, would always choose QT over any other framework, because the API and documentation is really great.